# Linq2Twitter how to get retweeters

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I need to get just users' ids who retweeted some status. But problem is that I can't find  [**GET statuses/retweeters/ids**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids) implementation in Linq2Twitter lib.

I've tried code below:

```
var retweets = (from u in twitterCtx.Status
            u.Type == StatusType.Retweets
            u.ID == statusId
            select u).ToList();
```

But according to [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3aid) I can get only 100 frist top tweets. Also playing with **MaxId** parameter din't give any results.

Please help!!!

**Update 1**

May be I wasn't too clear. I want to make request GET statuses/**retweeters**/ids, not  statuses/**retweetes**/:id

Comment: Well what are you expecting to get?

Comment: I want functionality of GET statuses/retweeters/ids from linq2twitter, to get all retweeters ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked in support for this query. You can get the functionality by downloading the [source code](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt). It will be in the next release.

Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
        var status =
            (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.Retweeters &&
                   tweet.ID == "210591841312190464"
             select tweet)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        status.Users.ForEach(
            userID => Console.WriteLine("User ID: " + userID));
```